# Uniform Convergence of uniformly bounded Operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

let $X,Y$ be Hilbertspaces with continuous embedding $X\hookrightarrow Y$  and $T_n$ a family of uniformly bounded linear operators, i.e. 
\begin{align*}
\exists c>0\;:\|T_n\|_{\mathcal{L}(X,Y)} \leq c \quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{align*}
Moreover, the operators should converge pointwise, i.e.
\begin{align*}
T_nx \to x \text{ in } Y \quad \forall x\in X
\end{align*}
Now, let $\{x_m\}_{m}\subset X$ be a bounded sequence. Does
\begin{align*}
\max_{m\in\mathbb{N}} \|x_m - T_nx_m\|_Y \to 0 \text{ as } n\to\infty
\end{align*}
hold? Thank you all.

Comment: How can $T_nx$ converge to $x$, if $x\in X$ and $T_nx\in Y$?

Comment: Does $X=Y$ ...?

Comment: Good point. Indeed $X\subset Y$ (with continuous embedding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Basically, specialize to the case $X=Y=\ell^2$ (separable), call $S_n=id-T_n$ and consider a dense sequence $\{x^m\}_{m\in\Bbb N}\in B(0,1)$. You are then asking if a bounded sequence $S_n$ such that $S_nx\to 0$ for all $x$ must satisfy $\lVert S_n\rVert\to 0$. This is not the case: call $S$ the backwards shift $(Sx)_k=x_{k+1}$ and consider $S_n=S^n$. $S^nx\to 0$ for all $x$ but $\lVert S^n\rVert=1$.